# What should you put on your face if you want to protect both yourself and others?

Tags: covid-19, epidemiology, face-mask-respirator

Surgical masks protect other people but provide almost no protection for the wearer (see https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2020/sep/14/facebook-posts/face-masks-wildfire-smoke-protection-and-covid-19-/).

Respirators (with valves) protect the wearer but don't protect those around you.

What should you put on your face if you want to protect both yourself and others?

Comment: What has your research revealed so far? Have you searched the questions on this subject already asked and answered here?

Comment: @CareyGregory Nope. Those that were automatically suggested didn't seem to match my request

Comment: Well, my point is that questions here are required to demonstrate some degree of prior research. The reasons are explained [in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411).

Comment: "Surgical masks,, almost no protection for the wearer" , care to provide a citation for that claim? Then compare it with "If worn properly, a surgical mask is meant to help block large-particle droplets, splashes, sprays, or splatter that may contain germs (viruses and bacteria), keeping it from reaching your mouth and nose." https://www.fda.gov/medical-devices/personal-protective-equipment-infection-control/n95-respirators-surgical-masks-and-face-masks#:~:text=If%20worn%20properly%2C%20a,respiratory%20secretions%20to%20others.

Comment: @CareyGregory I had read these two articles, among others (the latter is in Russian but references to English-language sources): https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2020/sep/14/facebook-posts/face-masks-wildfire-smoke-protection-and-covid-19-/ https://meduza.io/feature/2020/10/16/da-da-my-snova-pishem-o-maskah-rasskazyvaem-chto-tochno-izvestno-uchenym-ko-vtoroy-volne-koronavirusa

Comment: Your sources need to be in the question, not in comments, and they need to be English language only. Copying the relevant quotes into your question is preferred over just a link. You can use the Russian article if you translate the relevant quote.

Comment: This page (https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/prevent-getting-sick/cloth-face-cover-guidance.html) says that "the protective effects—how well the mask protects healthy people from breathing in the virus—are unknown."

Comment: Are you looking for a qualitative or a quantitative evaluation of the protective effects of mask wearing for health care workers - if so then that is what your question should state

Answer (score 4):

A mask. According to the [FDA](https://www.fda.gov/medical-devices/personal-protective-equipment-infection-control/n95-respirators-surgical-masks-and-face-masks#:%7E:text=If%20worn%20properly%2C%20a,respiratory%20secretions%20to%20others.)

> If worn properly, a surgical mask is meant to help block large-particle droplets, splashes, sprays, or splatter that may contain germs (viruses and bacteria), keeping it from reaching your mouth and nose. Surgical masks may also help reduce exposure of your saliva and respiratory secretions to others.

Other types on masks may afford further protection, but the surgical mask is generally accepted as an acceptable minimum. If a person is in a highly contaminated field an N95 mask or self-contained breathing apparatus. Likewise, if the wearer is significantly vulnerable a greater degree of protection is advisable.